# Pixel 3 not automatically connecting to 2.4 Ghz network

Tags: wi-fi, internet

I have a dual band router with 2.4 and 5 GHz channels, and the 2.4 GHz channel has a much better signal in my house, and is generally fast enough for the purposes I use my phone for.

Only problem is, the phone (Pixel 3, running Android 12) never saves the 2.4 GHz channel. Every time I want to use that channel after disconnecting, I have to manually re input my password, and while it connects, it's a bit inconvenient.

It's only my phone, as other devices in the house don't have this problem. The router is a Nokia Beacon 2.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Tried [resetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On4sR.png) wifi?

Comment: Also in network preferences, enable "turn 9n wifi automatically" - this may help

Comment: Tried both, neither worked

Comment: So your router uses different SSID for 2.4 and 5GHz Wifi? What channel is used for 2.4GHz Wifi and is this channel legal in your country (not all channels are allowed in all countries)?